# How to customize default CSV format in LibreOffice?

Tags: csv, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, utf-8

Every time I export my data to CSV (and I do it often) I have tick the "Edit filter settings" checkbox, choose UTF-8 for the encoding, and semicolon for the fields separator manually.

I do this dozens times a day. Is there a workaround to just set it up once and have it remember forever (until I decide to change it)?

Comment: Have you tried to use a macro, like presented here: http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/3383/export-to-csv-instead-of-saveas/